# Prove/Disprove that the asymptotes of a particular function always coincide with the extrema of a related function

Tags: roots

I have a function that is real valued in the interval $x\in \{-\infty,dw]$

$$
f(x)=\sqrt{-(x+w)}\sin\Bigl(b\sqrt{-(x+w)}\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(a\sqrt{-(x+dw)}\Bigr)
+c\Biggl[
\sqrt{-(x+dw)}\sin\Bigl(a\sqrt{-(x+dw)}\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(b\sqrt{-(x+w)}\Bigr)
\Biggr]
$$

where $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$, and $w$ are all real positive constants.

If I divide $f(x)$ by $\cos\Bigl(b\sqrt{-(x+w)}\Bigr)$, I get another related function

$$
u(x)=\cos\Bigl(a\sqrt{-(x+dw)}\Bigr) \tan\Bigl(b\sqrt{-(x+w)}\Bigr)
+c\Biggl[\frac{\sqrt{-(x+dw)}}{\sqrt{-(x+w)}}\sin\Bigl(a\sqrt{-(x+dw)}\Bigr)
\Biggr]
$$

Both of these functions share the same zeroes, and it *appears* (see the figure below) that the asymptotes of $u(x)$ coincide with the extrema of $f(x)$, although **I would like to be able to prove this algebraically**, something I'm having difficulty doing.

[image]

From the expression for $u(x)$, one can deduce that its asymptotes correspond to

$$
b\sqrt{-(x+w)}=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

so that the $n^{\text{th}}$ asymptote is at

$$
\bar{x}_n = -\Bigl[w+\Bigl(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2b}\Bigr)^2\Bigr] \forall n: \bar{x}_n < -dw$$

I got an expression for the derivative of $f(x)$ and set it to zero, but it yielded an unpromising jumble of terms that didn't help.

I'd appreciate suggestions for a clever way to go about proving this.

If it's provable, then that's **extremely** useful because I can then use the mid-point between asymptotes to get a very good initial guess for the zeroes of $f(x)$ which is my prime objective.

Thanks